How to Trigger an Azure Data Factory Pipeline on Failure of Another Pipeline
So I have this use case wherein I have a main ADF Pipeline let's say Pipeline-A and any kind of failure occurs in this pipeline I need to execute another pipeline which is responsible to run any azure databricks notebook.
I expect a pipeline wherein it executes in case of failure.

are both pipelines in same ADF?

Yes both the pipeline can be in the same ADF.

I think you need to use another parent pipeline for this requirement. Let me know If I can provide answer with that approach?

You can share your approach.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can use execute pipeline activity :

And in case of failure , you can trigger Databricks activity

Let's say we have a pipeline that contains multiple activities and I want the pipeline to trigger automatically if there is any kind of failure in the actual pipeline.
Also is there any way of doing this without the parent pipeline.

In the above scope, the execute pipeline activity is calling the pipeline that contains multiple activities and even if there is failure is any activity, the execute pipeline activity would fail and would then trigger the databricks activity.  There are other complicated ways like : You can enable email alert at the pipeline level for failure and once you receive any failure email, you can have other tools like power automate to trigger the databricks automatically
